# Javascript compress Images before Upload in Framework

Tags: javascript, image, upload, compression, image-resizing

Trying to upload images and compress them before I upload them. I am using cakephp 3.x (also for Form creation etc.), JIC (https://github.com/brunobar79/J-I-C) and I am resizing it before.

```
function ResizeImage() {
var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('images0').files;
var file = filesToUpload[0];

// Create an image
var img = document.createElement("img");
// Create a file reader
var reader = new FileReader();
// Set the image once loaded into file reader
reader.onload = function(e) {
    img.src = e.target.result;

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    //var canvas = $("<canvas>", {"id":"testing"})[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
    var MAX_HEIGHT = 400;
    var width = img.width;
    var height = img.height;

    if (width > height) {
        if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
            height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
            width = MAX_WIDTH;
        }
    } else {
        if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
            width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
        }
    }
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

    var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
    document.getElementById('preview_image0').src = dataurl;

    var source_img = document.getElementById("preview_image0");


    img.src = jic.compress(img,70,'jpg').src;

}
// Load files into file reader
reader.readAsDataURL(file);



}
```

Now I don´t want to use the upload function from JIC - instead use my own upload function in my controller.

Can I edit the xhr for the post in any way?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I assume with xhr you mean XMLHttpRequest, right? How do you want to "edit" that? This class is provided by the browser. You can't change its source.

Comment: I would recomend you switching `FileReader` for `URL.createObjectURL`

Comment: Well I am not sure about the terminology - I mean how can I upload the changed picture which I preview before.

Comment: You can use the upload function in `jic` *(that's exactly what this function seems to be made for)*, or you use your own upload function in your controller, as you mentioned. *I still don't get your problem/question*

Comment: Well I am using the upload in my Controller, but it is not saving the smaller image. It just uses the original uploaded one. So there seems to be a mistake in my JS.

Comment: Yea probably. A mistake in some code you don't show. Because this snippet doesn't mention the controller in any way. Neither how the infamous `upload` function works, nor where/how it is called, nor anything else. The only "(inter)action" of `ResizeImage` is changing the `src` of `#preview_image0`

Comment: It doesn´t make any diffrence. It uploads the file on my server (via                     move_uploaded_file($tmp, $uploadPath . DS . date("Ymd-His-") . $imgname); ) - I can access it and its the original. So it´s redundant information how I do it in the controller. The served image is not correct, and I gets served by HTML/JS

Comment: your snippet doesn't do anything upload-related. So no information about wich image is uploaded. Your whole snippet doesn't do anything at all, except of changing the preview image (to a resized version). The (main) error has to be somewhere else.